# What SQL query would I run to get a list of auctions I'm losing? (eBay example)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'll try to give an "eBay" example, I'm sure it will be the easiest way to ask this.

Imagine a table of `bids`:

```
bid_id | bid_from_user | bid_for_auction | bid_price
1      | 150           | 1               | 20
2      | 453           | 1               | 30
3      | 42            | 1               | 50
4      | 12            | 2               | 12
5      | 60            | 2               | 20
```

Imagine you need to list auctions which a certain person is **currently bidding on and losing**.

Therefore, our current user ID is `12`, so `bid_from_user='12'`

This user is currently bidding on auction id `2` with price `12` and is obviously losing, as there is another user bidding on the same auction with a higher price.

I don't want to list all the auctions the user is bidding on, I just want to list those the user is bidding on **and** losing (= not the ones he's winning).

So, what query do I run to do this?

Comment: It's just selecting rows for user that aren't in the maximum grouped by auction

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT b.bid_id, b.bid_from_user, b.bid_for_auction, b.bid_price
  FROM bids b
 WHERE b.bid_from_user = '12'
   AND EXISTS (
           SELECT 1 
             FROM bids x 
            WHERE x.bid_for_auction = b.bid_for_auction
              AND x.bid_price > b.bid_price
              AND x.bid_from_user <> b.bid_from_user);
```

---

Edit: The above would seem to be the cleanest, most legible solution; but here is an alternative in allowance for MySQL traditionally not handling subqueries well...

```
  SELECT b.bid_for_auction
    FROM bids b
         JOIN bids x ON x.bid_for_auction = b.bid_for_auction
     AND x.bid_price > b.bid_price
     AND x.bid_from_user <> b.bid_from_user
   WHERE b.bid_from_user = '12'
GROUP BY b.bid_for_auction;
```

Comment: Exactly - what is "select 1", please?

Comment: The `1` lets `EXISTS` know that _something_ was returned by the subquery. The `1` could be anything else you like, e.g. `42` or even `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks, that works, any chance I could rewrite that to also fetch auctions which the user is WINNING? I tried, but I failed ...

Comment: @RiMMER: try same query as first query in my above answer with `NOT EXISTS` in place of `EXISTS`. The thinking is that an auction a user is winning should have no higher bids from other users.

Answer (score 1):

The values in the select are just for proof:

```
  SELECT MAX( a.bid_price ), a.bid_for_auction, b.bid_price
    FROM bids a 
         INNER JOIN bids b ON a.bid_for_auction = b.bid_for_auction
   WHERE b.bid_from_user = 12 
GROUP BY bid_for_auction
  HAVING b.bid_price < MAX(a.bid_price);
```